# Wireshark does not see interfaces (winXP)

Tags: networking, wireshark, sniffing, protocol

Short story:

1. Wireshark is working....on my winXP-32b
2. ... usage ....
3. Long long time later
4. Wireshark does not work

   - It can't find any usefull interface (just VPN)
   - ipconfig /all

Ethernet adapter Wireless Network Connection:

```
    Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
    Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Dell Wireless 1490 Dual Band WLAN Mini-Card
    Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : SOME VALID MAC
```

Ethernet adapter eth0:

```
    Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : xxxx
    Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Broadcom 440x 10/100 Integrated Controller
    Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : SOME VALID MAC
    Dhcp Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
    Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
    IP Address. . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.12.68
    Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
    Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.....
```

.....
Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:

```
    Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
    Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Fortinet virtual adapter
    Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : SOME VALID MAC
```

5. Following steps didn't help:

   ```
   Several Wireshark re-installation
   Several LIBPCAP re installation
   SP3 for winXP
   ```

Any ideas welcome.

Comment: Have you configured your NIC to run in promiscuous mode?

Comment: Even here http://www.ethereal.com/faq#q7.6 they don't write how to turn it on.

Answer (score 1):

Start the wireshark with sudo or from a root or admin account. Capturing and listing interfaces need root privileges.

source: [wireshark wiki](http://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/CapturePrivileges)

Answer (score 0):

Ideas to try:

1. Uninstall Wireshark and WinPcap ***using*** [**Revo**](http://www.revouninstaller.com/), then reinstall.
2. If you have upgraded Wireshark and/or WinPcap, go back to the versions that worked.
3. If an interface doesn't show up in the list of interfaces in the "Interface:" field, and you know the name of the interface, try entering that name in the "Interface:" field.
4. Check any item that might apply in the Wireshark Preferences, as network interfaces can be marked as hidden.
5. Follow troubleshooting hints in the Wireshark FAQ section [Capturing packets on Windows](http://www.wireshark.org/faq.html#q8.1).